# Error trying to set up db-less kong using docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, api-gateway, kong

I am trying to set up kong db-less
I have created a docker file as below:

```
FROM kong
USER 0
RUN mkdir -p /kong/declarative/
COPY kong.yml /usr/local/etc/kong/kong.yml
USER kong
```

and a docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
 kong-net:

services:
  kong:
    container_name: kong-dbless
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - kong-net
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=off
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/usr/local/etc/kong/kong.yml
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8444:8444"
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:8443"
```

and kong.yaml is as below

```
 _format_version: "1.1"
 _transform: true

 services:
 - host: mockbin.org
   name: example_service
   port: 80
   protocol: http
   routes:
 - name: example_route
     paths:
     - /mock
     strip_path: true
```

I run `docker-compose up` but I errors in the log

*- [+] Running 1/0

- Container kong-dbless  Created   0.0s
- Attaching to kong-dbless
- kong-dbless  | 2022/04/29 01:31:52 [warn] 1#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master    process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in    /usr/local/kong/nginx.conf:6
- kong-dbless  | nginx: [warn] the "user"    directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user    privileges, ignored in /usr/local/kong/nginx.conf:6
- kong-dbless  |    2022/04/29 01:31:52 [error] 1#0: init_by_lua error:    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:553: error parsing declarative    config file /kong/declarative/kong.yml:
- kong-dbless  |    /kong/declarative/kong.yml: No such file or directory
- kong-dbless  |    stack traceback:
- kong-dbless  |  [C]: in function 'error'
- kong-dbless  |  /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:553: in function 'init'
- kong-dbless  | nginx: [error] init_by_lua error:    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:553: error parsing declarative    config file /kong/declarative/kong.yml:
- kong-dbless  |  [C]: in    function 'error'
- kong-dbless  |     /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:553: in function 'init'
- kong-dbless  |  init_by_lua:3: in main chunk*

Does anybody know what the problem is and how should I fix it?

---

Also I tried this but did not work:

Dockerfile

```
FROM kong
COPY kong.yml /
RUN cp /etc/kong/kong.conf.default /etc/kong/kong.conf
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
 kong-net:

services:
  kong:
    container_name: kong-dbless
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
#    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - kong-net
    healthcheck:
      test: [ “CMD”, “curl”, “-f”, “http://kong:8000” ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=off
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=kong.yml
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8444:8444"
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:8443"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
FROM kong
USER 0
RUN mkdir -p /kong/declarative/
COPY declarative/kong.yml /kong/declarative/
RUN cp /etc/kong/kong.conf.default /etc/kong/kong.conf
USER kong
```

and

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
 kong-net:

services:
  kong:
    container_name: kong
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - kong-net
    healthcheck:
      test: [ “CMD”, “curl”, “-f”, “http://kong:8000” ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=off
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/kong/declarative/kong.yml
    ports:
      - "8444:8444"
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:8443"
```